# Bounds related to Monomial Symmetric Functions

Tags: symmetric-functions, symmetric-polynomials

Two of the well studied bases for symmetric functions over $\mathbb{Q}$ are the monomial symmetric functions $\{ m_{\lambda} \}_{\lambda \text{ a partition}}$ and the power sum symmetric functions $\{ p_{\lambda} \}_{\lambda \text{ a partition}}$. Let $a_{\lambda,\lambda'}$ be the coefficients which allow one to pass between the two bases:
$$m_{\lambda} = \sum_{\lambda' \vdash |\lambda|} a_{\lambda, \lambda'} p_{\lambda'}.$$
These coefficients do not seem to be well understood in general, and I did not find them in Macdonald's symmetric functions book. For each partiton $\lambda$ of $n$, what I am interested in is an upper bound for the following sum:
$$F(\lambda)=\sum_{\lambda' \vdash n} |a_{\lambda, \lambda'}| z^{\ell(\lambda')}.$$
Here $z$ is some positive parameter, and $\ell(\lambda')$ is the number of parts in $\lambda'$.

**Question:** What kind of upper bounds can be obtained for $F(\lambda)$?

**Example:** There is an interesting example in which one can obtain a closed form formula for $F(\lambda)$, but it is not necessarily a representative example. When $$\lambda=(1,1,\ldots,1) \vdash n,$$ then $m_{\lambda}$ is nothing but $e_{n}$, the $n$-th elementary symmetric function. In that case, $a_{\lambda,\lambda'}$ was computed by Girard and Newton: $|a_{\lambda,\lambda'}| = \mathrm{P}_{S_n}(\lambda')$ is the probability that a uniformly chosen permutation from $S_n$ has cycle type $\lambda'$. Moreover, it can be shown that
$$F(\lambda)=\sum_{\lambda' \vdash n} \mathrm{P}_{S_n}(\lambda') z^{\ell(\lambda')} = \binom{z+n-1}{n-1},$$
for instance by using the exponential formula for permutations.

**Remark:** In fact, I am tackling the sum $G(n)=\sum_{\lambda \vdash n, \ell(\lambda)\le m} F(\lambda)$, where $m$ is an additional parameter. My hope is that pointwise bounds for $F(\lambda)$ will be good enough in order to bound $G(n)$, but perhaps $G$ has to be tackled directly.

Comment: The $a_{\lambda, \lambda^{\prime}}$ are given a combinatorial expression in equation (11) of [Ömer Eg̃eciog̃lu, Jeffrey B. Remmel, *Brick tabloids and the connection matrices between bases of symmetric functions*, Discrete Applied Mathematics, Volume 34, Issues 1--3, 21 November 1991, Pages 107--120](https://doi.org/10.1016/0166-218X(91)90081-7). Not sure if it helps you with your bounds, though.

Comment: @darij I wasn't familiar with this paper, and it is already helpful - I guess experts knew this by other methods, but the formula in the paper implies that if $a_{\lambda, \lambda'}$ is non-zero then $\ell(\lambda')\le \ell(\lambda)$, which already helps me in bounding $G(n)$. Their formula also immediately gives some crude effective bounds which do not follow from the definition.

Comment: Why did you delete this post twice?